# Story/Novel where Old Ones dominate modern world

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, cthulhu-mythos

I'm pretty sure I read this in the '90s; I don't recall whether I'm recalling a single section of a longer novel, or a short story.

It *may* have been part of a story involving a cross-timeline travelling main character. The detail I recall is that something had happened, perhaps someone trying to make a movie out of the Necronomicon, and the Old Ones now existed in the real world and were dominant, though it seemed  mostly that they acted as "over-administrators", and life was mostly normal. The reason I think it might be involved with cross-time travel is because there was an "infodump" explaining this in the form of someone explaining this to the viewpoint character.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but I've seen good answers come out of less here... help?

Comment: There are some similarities to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Five which does involve Old Ones who are less direct in their effects, and a time jump of 10 years.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Definitely not; what I read absolutely predates that...

Comment: Could it be "Resume with Monsters" by William Browning Spencer? That has the Old Ones living in the real world, but no cross-timeline travelling.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - Neither the title nor the author rings a bell, but I've made a note to try to find it and check it... Can you provide additional info?

Comment: Posting [A Study In Emerald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Study_in_Emerald) by Nial Gaiman, but it has no time traveling aspects.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Definitely not - this was "modern" in the twentieth-century sense, not Victorian, and was definitely not a detective story, much less a Holmes pastiche. However, thanks for this; I'm definitely putting this on my to-be-acquired list...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin There are many reviews at goodreads.com. Here is a sample: "Angsty author, Philip Kenan, works for Ralph’s One Day Resumes... Philip believes that his frequent job loss and daily brushes with disappointment and frustration are the result of a vast inter-dimensional conspiracy orchestrated by the “elder gods” of the Cthulhu Mythos and that his boss and most of his co-workers are really inhuman servants of these deities."

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - OK, I can definitely say that this isn't it; the existence of the Old Ones (referred to in the story as "cthulhi") was open, not concealed.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Ah! "cthulhi" rings a bell. Could it be "Parallelities" by Alan Dean Foster?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - I'll check; ADF is an author I've read in the past, so it's not impossible.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez From the description, I was pretty sure it wasn't "Resume with Monsters", but I was really happy to see someone else had read the book. I especially liked the correspondence at the end...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the OP remembering the word "cthulhi" in the comments, I think this must be "[Parallelities](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25624)" a novel by Alan Dean Foster, published in 1998.

A tabloid reporter, Max Parker, acquires the ability to slip between parallel worlds. In one of these worlds the Cthulhu mythos has comes into being, because of a movie made about the Necronomicon:

> It was all the fault of that picture they were making. That damn
> picture. The one about the Necronomicon. Some fool produce got ahold
> of a copy of the real thing, not one of the cheap fictional fakes, and
> thought it would make the basis for a good horror film... So a script
> was drawn up, and principal photography started, and when they read
> the critical words for the hundredth time, all very innocent and all,
> the Earth trembled and the skies opened up and the Great Old Ones
> awoke and began their triumphant return

As the question says, life went on much as normal, despite mankind being ruled by cephalopodian monstrosities:

> It's really not so bad. Except for the day when we lost Minneapolis
> there hasn't been much of what you'd call mass affliction. The Great
> Old Ones want respect and the occasional juicy young sacrifice, and
> that's all.

Comment: After obtaining a copy and reading it, this is indeed it! Have some rep!

Comment: Glad to have helped!